# How to look at only the 3rd value in all lists in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists and I want to be able to refer to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. column in a list of lists. Here is my code for the list:

```
matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 0, 3],
    [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [7, 0, 8, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
```

I want to be able to say something like:

```
matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 0, 3],
    [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [7, 0, 8, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
if (The fourth column in this matrix does not have any 1's in it):
    (then do something)
```

I want to know what the python syntax would be for the stuff in parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if all(row[3] != 1 for row in matrix):
    # do something
```

The `row[3]` part takes a look at the fourth element of a row, the `for row in matrix` part looks at all the rows in the matrix - this produces a list with all the fourth elements in all the rows, that is, the whole fourth column. Now if it is true for all the elements in the fourth column that they're different from one, then the condition is satisfied and you can do what you need inside the `if`.

A more traditional approach would be:

```
found_one = False
for i in xrange(len(matrix)):
    if matrix[i][3] == 1:
        found_one = True
        break
if found_one:
    # do something
```

Here I'm iterating over all the rows (`i` index) of the fourth column (`3` index), and checking if an element is equal to one: `if matrix[i][3] == 1:`. Notice that the `for` cycle goes from the `0` index up to the "height" of the matrix minus one, that's what the `xrange(len(matrix))` part says.

Comment: So row[3] would look at all rows in the fourth position? I am assuming when you said " the for col in matrix part looks at all the rows in the matrix" you meant for row in matrix. could I somehow make separate lists of these? Somehow compile the values into new lists so I could get counts and things?

Comment: Not exactly, `row[3]` looks at the fourth element in a given row, and `row[3] for row in matrix` looks at all the fourth elements of all the rows. The expression `[row[x] for row in matrix]` will return all the elements of the `x` row in a separate list.

Comment: If I wanted to have a different condition than != would that be possible?

Comment: Sure thing @TerriMoore, any operator that evaluates to a boolean value would work (examples: ==, !=, >, <, >=, <=)

Comment: Thank you, the up vote was for kindly answering all of my questions today and last night and providing a very through answer. Unlike some of the other people to answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: Oh no! I need to ask you another question! If I have a number can I make it figure out which column its in and use that as the row[3]? Would you like to move this to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6163/discussion-between-oscar-lopez-and-terri-moore)

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to perform what you asked is to do a list comprehension

> if (The fourth column in this matrix does not have any 1's in it):

translates in:

```
>>>if not any([1 == row[3] for row in matrix])
```

However, depending on how often you need to perform this operation, how big is your matrix, etc... you might wish to look into [numpy](https://numpy.org/) as it is easier (and remarkably faster) to address columns. An example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5))
>>> matrix
array([[3, 0, 9, 9, 3],
       [5, 7, 7, 7, 6],
       [5, 4, 6, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 5, 0, 5],
       [3, 9, 7, 8, 6]])
>>> matrix[..., 3]  #fourth column
array([9, 7, 2, 0, 8])
```

Comment: I am not looking at rows that I know how to do. What I am lacking is a good way to make columns in my "matrix."

Comment: Before you didn't have any of the stuff about numpy. You just edited it. I will look at it again.

Comment: +1 to suggest the use of numpy. I think is the right choice for this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

```
if 1 in [row[3] for row in matrix]:
```

Comment: This again would help me do rows but what I am looking for is a way to define columns. Columns being say the 5th value in all of the lists. A kind of "vertical row."

Comment: But that's exactly what this gives you. `row[3] for row in matrix` is the column in position 3.

Comment: So it isn't looking at the third row, but at the third value in all rows?

Comment: Yes. It's called a list comprehension (or a generator expression). Try it out in the interpreter: `print [row[3] for row in matrix]` will give you `[5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 3, 0]`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to grab all of the values from the third position in all rows and make it into a list? If I were able to do that then I would be able to do counts among other things.

Comment: I don't know how to make myself any clearer: that's **exactly** what the list comprehension does.